# porque me sale error al imprimir el vector? debo llenar el vector con n numeros aleatorios entre 0 y 20 flotantes

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 

    { 
     {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       Vector orden = new Vector();
        System.out.print("Digite el orden del vector ");
        
       int n = sc.nextInt();
       
       orden.setN(n);
       orden.floatAleatorio();
     
      }
    }
```

Esta es la clase: donde está el vector, debo reservar espacio en memoria al vector con el constructor y luego llenar el vector con n números aleatorios entre 0 y 20 flotantes

```
public class Vector
{
    private int n;

    private float vector[];

    private int vector2[];
    
    public Vector()
    {
        n = 1;
    }
    
    public Vector(int n,float vector[],int vector2[])
    {
        this.n = n;
        this.vector = new float[n];
        this.vector2 = new int[n];
    }
    
    public void setN(int n)
    {
        this.n = n;
    }
    
    public float[] floatAleatorio()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<vector.length ;i++)
            vector[i] = (float)(Math.random()*20);  

        return vector;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Porque setN no cambia el tamaño del vector ni los inicializa. Algo como lo que haces en el segundo constructor

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio